# how to reduce by key in Apache Beam using Java and get this output key=value

Tags: java, apache-beam

noob here! I am trying to learn Apache Beam in Java but I'm stuck without no progress!
imagine I have a file with this format:

```
957149WC,Kyle,10,Accounts,1-01-2019
241316NX,Kumiko,10,Accounts,1-01-2019
796656IE,Kyle,10,Accounts,1-01-2019
331593PS,Beryl,20,HR,1-01-2019
560447WH,Olga,20,HR,1-01-2019
```

I want to know how can I count the number of people in rows contains "Accounts" and achive this output:

```
Kyle=2
Kumiko=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostafa if you want to use Apache Beam in Java first add these two dependencies in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then to achieve your desired output you can do something like this (it is not perfect but gives you the idea)

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
p
        .apply(TextIO.read().from("input.txt"))
        .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.lists(TypeDescriptors.strings()))
                .via(l -> Arrays.asList(l.split(","))))
        .apply(Filter.by(element -> element.get(3).equals("Accounts")))
        .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptors.integers()))
                .via(element -> KV.of(element.get(1), 1)))
        .apply(Combine.perKey((a, b) -> a + b))
        .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings()).via(element -> element.getKey() + "=" + element.getValue()))
        .apply(TextIO.write().to("data/output").withNumShards(1).withSuffix(".txt"));

p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

which result in :

```
Kyle=2
Kumiko=1
```